# PHP Multiple Rows for single Record into 1 Row with multiple columns

Tags: php, arrays, json, mysqli, multiple-columns

So, this is going to sound weird and I will try my best to explain.

I have a mySQL table that has several thousands rows ( about 600K ) and I need to output the records in that table into a CSV file. The problem is that the information in the table is stored in a per row format instead of many columns. Similar to the following:

1|1|John
2|1|Smith
3|1|Green
4|1|Car
5|2|Jane
6|2|Doe
7|2|Blue
8|2|Bike

I want to take that and output as follows. It could be an array.

1|John|Smith|Green|Car
2|Jane|Doe|Blue|Bike

I have tried doing a query using mysqli and then doing an array and looping through it and so forth. It always takes a very long time. I need to do this via a combination of PHP and mySQL. Problem is that I don't even know how to get started. Sorry if it doesn't make sense. I can elaborate.

Comment: There's no question here man. You wrote a wishlist. What do you expect to get as answer?

Comment: I submitted by accident without having a chance to finish. I hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: You do it in chunks. Not all at once. Select 10 records at a time, process them, stick it to the csv, move on to next 10. You have 600 000 rows, if you attempt to select everything - it takes time and occupies a nice chunk of memory. Since there's no code, it's difficult to tell you anything else.

Comment: u just ask no feedback

Answer (score 0):

I would do this (replace column/table names by your database ones ) :

```
SELECT CONCAT(t.name_of_your_second_column, ';',  GROUP_CONCAT(name_of_your_third_column SEPARATOR ';'))
FROM NAME_OR_YOUR_TABLE t
GROUP BY t.name_of_your_second_column
```

Result would be :

1;John;Smith;Green;Car

2;Jane;Doe;Blue;Bike

Loop on the result array.
Then juste write each row as is in your csv file, ";" being the separator

A little google "write csv file with php" should do the rest, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

quickest method as i see it to use the full power of php and mysql would be two queries:

```
select distinct col2
```

store your result, and "for each" with that value so you get one query for each on the second round.

```
select col1,col3 where col2={value} order by col1
```

now you have your output ready to iterate through each record with another "for each" to display or store the records. before the for each, put in your iterative line number and start of the line. then drop in each value and a separator, and drop in the end line outside the for each.

Since your initial db query will have a limited response (single column, distinct values) it won't be too long (timewise) or too large (memory wise). And the individual queries should share memory so each one will be tiny and fast. this could also avoid locking the db for a long time (depending on your engine this could make a difference for other users).